# mongoid uniqueness validation many-to-many relation

Tags: many-to-many, mongoid, validation, unique

I have following association

```
class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document
  employee_id :name
 references_many :companies, stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :employees
end

class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
 references_many :employees, stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :companies
end
```

Now How can I check the uniqueness of `employee_id` of employee within a single `company`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Gagan. First, this line in your Employee model needs to be corrected:

```
employee_id :name
```

For the validation, you should be able to do this:

```
class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :employee_id, :type => Integer

  references_many :companies, :stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :employees

  validates_uniqueness_of :employee_id
end
```

You can test it easily like this:

```
>> e = Employee.create :employee_id => 10
 => #

>> Employee.new(:employee_id => 10).valid?
 => false
```

Comment: yeah.. what you have written is absolutely right just for a single employee model. But what i want is to be employee_id to be unique in a single company. Two employee can have same employee_id but they should be in a different company. I hope you understand what i mean to say.

Comment: I got the same problem, I think it's easiest to write your own validator. I'll probably do it next week, if so I can post it here.